# 100% left div section required

Tags: html, css

I have two divs (red and yellow). Red div has 100% height and Yellow div in fixed 1000 pixel. I want red div 100% of the window screen even I scroll down the page, but it is not taking 100% height of the browser screen. I tried to find so many examples but failed to resolve my issues. Please guide…

Here is the example i have done.

http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/Ff6v5/

Comment: for a better design, read this: http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/four-methods-to-create-equal-height-columns/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ff6v5/16/) what you want?

Then you need to change three things:

1. body's and html's height to min-height;
2. body's and html's position to relative;
3. you don't need !important in .left-menu's height.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your CSS, should do the trick:

```
.left-menu{ width:200px; background:red; position:fixed; top:0; bottom:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### It doing what it is suppose to do !!!

This is really a misunderstanding.

Your style of `height: 100%` applies to `.left-menu`. But inside this `.left-menu`, you have another div called `.left-footer`, which has green as its background. So, *the CSS is doing what is coded to do.*

It order to span the red above the entire left area, you **dont have to do anything.** It is already doing that. For the proof see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ff6v5/17/).

So, there is nothing to fix. This is a ***design flaw***.